# Adding existing project to reinstalled XAMPP

Tags: xampp, drupal

I've installed Windows 8 on my computer, so I had to transfer all my files to an extern HDD. I thought I could just re-install XAMPP and copy my project in the folder and continue working on it, but that's not working.

I'm not a pro in XAMPP but I realized I probably have to import the database. What do I need to import it?

I hope I can still continue working on my project, if not, is there a way I can use the content again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you worked programmatically till now, you just have to go and install your website, otherwise you have to create the database, and put the old database in there. After that you have to modify the `settings.php` from `sites/default`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used to go to localhost and create a new website. What file is the database I have to import?

Comment: When you transfered the files to your extern HDD, did you export the database? 'cuse if so, you use that exported file of the database. If not, you kind of lost everything, if you didn't worked programmatically

Comment: Export the database by going to localhost/phpmyadmin? I transfered the whole xampp folder, I'm new to xampp so I didn't think about that :/ I can't use the content I've created anymore? It's my old hdd (now I'm using ssd), maybe I can just put it in my laptop again and export it?

Comment: It's ok, I have it! I just replaced the new c:/xampp file with the old c:/xampp file with my websites in and it works! :) Thanks